# sosex alternative for linux .net core memory dumps

Tags: linux, .net-core, coredump

I am trying to analyze a 10GB memory dump of a .NET Core linux process. I am trying to use the `dotnet dump analyze` command, but there is a problem - `gcroot` gets stuck for hours producing no result.

I am accustomed to analyzing memory dumps of the windows .Net processes using WinDBG and sosex. There we can build the heap index (`bhi`) once and it is used by other commands, like the ultra useful `refs` or `mdt` or `strings` commands. Sosex was exceptionally useful and it worked. Here with the linux dump I must be doing something wrong, because I am unable to get `gcroot` working.

Has anyone been successful in analyzing 10GB memory dumps? I am able to run `dumpheap`, but without references to the objects of interest I have no idea how to proceed. In general, I feel the core dump debugging experience in linux is abysmal when compared to that using WinDBG + sosex on windows. I must be doing something terribly wrong. Is there a sosex alternative for linux?

P.S.
I do not know if it matters, but I am using WSL2, so not a real Linux box.

Answer (score 0):

gcroot has to analyze the managed heap to find any and all references to the object specified. It's a labor-intensive process and with large dump files can take a really, really long time. I don't think SOSEX has been updated for quite some time and likely will not work.